# 95 Honda Civic Dax 95 hooked up jumper cables a sparks and smoke coming From the cables and now her car won’t start is that electrical

Tags: starting

[image]  95 Honda Civic DX five-speed two door

Comment: Her car is the Honda? Which car won’t start?

Comment: One of my friends had cables wrong way on a jump, got the sparks. Engine computer started throwing loads of codes car was running in limp mode, could not change out of first. Root cause was a blow fuse. I would check all the fuses as a base line and hope one took the brunt